# Creating a Table Showing All Pair Combinations of Values in 1 Column Based on Values in a Different Column - Excel / Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, formula, spreadsheet, method-combination

I have this table showing the names of the employees who worked on jobs where each job can be worked on by more than one employee:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk6dU.png)

And I would like to create a new table comparing the names of the employees who worked on the same job so we could eventually compare their answers, two employees at time. It should look something like this:

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA0qf.png)

So if a job was answered by 4 people, then I should end up with 6 rows for the job (4C2) and if it was answered by 16 people, then I should have 120 rows (16C2).

Is there any way I could do this in Excel or in Power BI?

Answer (score 1):

In `Power Query`:

1. Select the *Employee 1 Name* and *Employee 2 Name* columns and then `Unpivot Columns`
2. Select the *Job* and resulting *Value* columns and then `Remove Duplicates`
3. Remove the *Attribute* column